# Не только + деепричастие: забыла, ставится ли запятая против интонации именно в этом случае

Tags: пунктуация

> Я всегда с удовольствием **слушала их не только находясь на сцене**, но
>   временами делала громче трансляцию некоторых музыкальных номеров, сидя
>   в гримёрке, в ожидании своего выхода.

Comment: Что-то здесь не так. Если это устойчивое сочетание "не только, но и", то требуется дополнительное *и* — и тогда все предложение должно быть перестроено. В противном случае нужно убрать *но*.

Comment: Нет. Не только с удовольствием слушала на сцене, но временами усиливала звук из-за сцены. Возможно, с *и* лучше, но - правило редактора - ЕСЛИ МОЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ, НУЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ! Впрочем, автор всё прочтёт...

Comment: Вы переставили "не только" в другое место. Если еще добавить *и* после *но*, то формальности будут соблюдены (не только слушала, но и усиливала звук). Вопрос, насколько это искажает смысл. Смысл-то в том, что слушала не только на сцене, но и в гримерке.

Comment: Ок! Принято! )))

Comment: Присоединяюсь ко мнению М_Г! Полностью согласен со всем!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Я всегда с удовольствием слушала их не только находясь на сцене, но и сидя в гримёрке в ожидании своего выхода: временами делала громче трансляцию некоторых музыкальных номеров.***

1. [Каковы правила постановки запятых при ДО](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=923a1133-9e7f-4a4e-9bf0-440e72325629):

**Не обособляются** деепричастные обороты, тесно связанные по содержанию со сказуемым и образующие смысловой центр высказывания:

***Студенты приобретают знания не только слушая лекции, но и на производственной практике.***

2. Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы **только, лишь,** интонационно не отделяется от предшествующей части предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), но **запятая перед ним обычно ставится**: *Понять это произведение можно, только учитывая условия его создания; Выучить иностранный язык можно, лишь постоянно занимаясь им.*

Но (при тесном слиянии оборота со сказуемым):

***Они встретились только будучи уже взрослыми.*** [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=82)

Comment: Катюша, Вы гений!

Comment: Ах, если бы... Спасибо!)